# Angular Loop using directives and accessing model value

Tags: angular

In Angular 2+ is there a way to create a directive, then loop through all of the fields?

For example:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myvar1" myDirective></input> (Typed "Hello")
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myvar2" myDirective></input> (Typed "There")

 let concatResult : string ="";
 foreach myDirective {
 concatResult += myDirective:ngModelVar;
}
```

Result would be "HelloThere"

Edit: Let me clarify, I'm wanting to apply a directive to indicate my own special validation, to basically tell my validation function which inputs to loop through. I remember in jQuery you can do something by enumerating fields with the same CSS class, wasn't sure if Angular directives let you accomplish something like this. My forms are template forms, but I'm not using form submit, instead I'm just firing off javascript functions from buttons, and reading the model. Right now, I'm just manually checking each model on in my own validation function, and creating error messages.

```
validate() : boolean {
  if (currentPerson.name?.length > 0) ...
}
```